# Django app works via manage.py runserver but page rendered via mod_uwsgi fails to refer to static elements

Tags: django, nginx, mod-wsgi

I am at the end of my rope here... and plan to start digging into Django source code to figure this out.

I have a Django app that has been created in the standard fashion via start project. So far I have been testing it via "`python manage.py runserver 8081`".

Now I am trying to put this behind Nginx using mod_uwsgi.

So I test it using the excellent instructions over [here](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html).

My ini file looks as follows:

```
uwsgi]
chdir=<path_to_my_project>
module=<application>.wsgi:application
pidfile=/tmp/<pid_file_name>
max-requests=5000
daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/<log_file_name>
env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<application>.settings
http-socket=127.0.0.1:50000
```

So I start the app using:

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

All seems to look good:

1. Log file at "/var/log/uwsgi/" created: Looks good.
2. Directory is changed: Looks good. Log file indicates so.
3. Module is loaded: Assume that it has... I don't see any error message in the logs.
4. pidfile is created: Looks good. I do see the correct PID number in the file. 
   Tested the closing of the process via SIGINT.
5. Listening at http-socket: Looks good.

---

**PROBLEM:**
When I hit the site via `http://site_url`; I get the HTML page in my browser. But none of the CSS styles are reflected. Also, none of my java-script functions are executed. So not sure what is amiss.

FYI: I noticed the following lines in the log:

```
[pid: 15730|app: 0|req: 7/7] 127.0.0.1 () {36 vars in 696 bytes} [Thu Apr 25 16:40:50 2013] GET / => generated 11774 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 59 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 15730|app: 0|req: 8/8] 127.0.0.1 () {36 vars in 710 bytes} [Thu Apr 25 16:40:50 2013] GET /static/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js => generated 2874 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 1 headers in 51 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 15730|app: 0|req: 9/9] 127.0.0.1 () {36 vars in 727 bytes} [Thu Apr 25 16:40:50 2013] GET /static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css => generated 2877 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 1 headers in 51 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 15730|app: 0|req: 10/10] 127.0.0.1 () {36 vars in 716 bytes} [Thu Apr 25 16:40:50 2013] GET /static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js => generated 2883 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 1 headers in 51 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 15730|app: 0|req: 11/11] 127.0.0.1 () {32 vars in 570 bytes} [Thu Apr 25 16:40:50 2013] GET /favicon.ico => generated 2808 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 1 headers in 51 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 15730|app: 0|req: 12/12] 127.0.0.1 () {36 vars in 696 bytes} [Thu Apr 25 16:40:51 2013] GET / => generated 11774 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 59 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 15730|app: 0|req: 13/13] 127.0.0.1 () {36 vars in 710 bytes} [Thu Apr 25 16:40:51 2013] GET /static/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js => generated 2874 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 1 headers in 51 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 15730|app: 0|req: 14/14] 127.0.0.1 () {36 vars in 727 bytes} [Thu Apr 25 16:40:51 2013] GET /static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css => generated 2877 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 1 headers in 51 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 15730|app: 0|req: 15/15] 127.0.0.1 () {36 vars in 716 bytes} [Thu Apr 25 16:40:51 2013] GET /static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js => generated 2883 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 1 headers in 51 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 15730|app: 0|req: 16/16] 127.0.0.1 () {32 vars in 570 bytes} [Thu Apr 25 16:40:51 2013] GET /favicon.ico => generated 2808 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 1 headers in 51 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

---

Is there some additional config that I seem to have missed?

Would greatly appreciate your time and input. I will leave a solution in case I find one.

Best...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the section on the django docs about serving static files. The rules for mod_wsgi apply to mod_uwsgi. A more easy approach is configuring uWSGI to serve static files:
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/StaticFiles.html

Check the part about offloading if your site is pretty loaded

Generally avoid using django for serving static files

Comment: Thx Sir. Will do and report back.

Answer (score -1):

I am not using nginx but Apache, running `mod_wsgi`.
There I have the possibility to use

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/django-project/static/
```

All files are in my directory and accesaible at `http://example.com/static/`.
So maybe you can [do the same](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias) with nginx.

Edit: 
This skips the process of wsgi/cgi/uwsgi and allows the http daemon to handle the static files directly. There is no need for python to parse these kind of requests - because they're only accessing static files.

Comment: you might want to expand a bit on the answer. Please explain why this is a better solution and include some relevant code snippets that illustrate your point.